# How to set ListView style in the resource?

Tags: android, styles

I want to set the ListView style in the Theme, so that all the ListView of the Application will inherit the style. My code looks like this:

```
style.xml

<!-- Light Theme of the Application -->
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Green</item>
    <item name="android:absListViewStyle">@style/AbsListViewStyle.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="AbsListViewStyle.Light" parent="android:style/Widget.AbsListView">
    <item name="background">@color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/light_gray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/actionbar_background_green</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">false</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

I set the theme of the Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.
But it seems that the style is not applied to the ListView.
Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I got the reason, I should use android:listViewStyle attribute instead of absListViewStyle:

style.xml

```
<!-- Light Theme of the Application -->
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Green</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewStyle.Light" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="background">@color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/light_gray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/actionbar_background_green</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">false</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

In this way I can apply ListView style in the Theme xml.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set it on your ListView in xml for list view add:

```
    style="@style/AbsListViewStyle.Light"
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to change the ListView style according to the application Theme?

Comment: you should extend your style by them that is set in application